# What happens to the essence?

Tags: ninja-gaiden-sigma-2

In *Ninja Gaiden Sigma 2* (PS3), when you use the ultimate technique and absorb the surrounding essence, does it heal/give ki/money or is it just consumed towards the speed charging of UT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence you absorb to quick charge the Ultimate Technique is used to charge the technique and provides no other benefit. However, this is counteracted by the fact that enemies killed with the UT drop more essence - either 300% of normal for charge level one, or 700% of normal for charge level two.